# BitBucket: How to list the users I have invited to my project

Tags: bitbucket

I have a private repository and I have invited several users to let them get the code. Now I want to see the which users could do that.

But I cannot find a way to list all the users that are able to access this repository. Anyone could help?

And how can I revoke the access invitation?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Go to your repo's `Setting/Administration page` > `Access management`.

It will list all the **users** and **groups** who have the right there.

And you can also delete the access right for given user or group there.

### EDIT 2019

It's repo | Settings | User and group access

Comment: Thanks, it is a small icon on the right which I ignored at first time.

Comment: Currently it's here: `Settings > Users on plan` ; Can be found directly at:
https://bitbucket.org/account/user/[ACCT_USERNAME]/plan-users/

Comment: @gnB Today, that link looks like [this](https://imgur.com/a/jai5ktE) and I don't see anywhere for pending invitations? Does this mean I haven't sent my invitation properly?

Comment: @buddyp450 Those bitbucket links seem to shift every now and then.  The way I verify my invitations is : I **do not rely** on an invite email being sent from BitBucket, but instead just send a direct email to each person with link to the repo.  If they can access it, you know it's working  - *not fancy, but certainly functional*

Answer (score 7):

It is moved to other section. Try `PLANS AND BILLING` > `Plan details`

Comment: This is what I was looking for, to get the list of all users in my plan

Answer (score 2):

As of February 2022, this is how you can see the users in your Bitbucket workspace.

https://bitbucket.org -> {workspace} -> Settings -> Users on plan

or

[https://bitbucket.org/{username}](https://bitbucket.org/%7Busername%7D) -> Settings -> Users on plan

or

[https://bitbucket.org/{username}/workspace/settings/plan-users/](https://bitbucket.org/%7Busername%7D/workspace/settings/plan-users/)